# How to write nginx rewrite rule to catch /static in relative path

Tags: regex, nginx, rules

I want to rewrite following URLs. There can be several paths before static. So I want to remove all of them and just get the url starting with /static

```
*/static/js/52.eebbab07.chunk.j
someurl/subpath1/subpath2/static/js/52.eebbab07.chunk.j
```

to this

```
/static/js/52.eebbab07.chunk.j
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
rewrite /static/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
```

The `rewrite` directive allows to capture trailing part of URI after `/static`, and the substitution (second argument) can use it as `$1`.

Comment: Yeah, how about? Does that resolve the given problem? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This is correct but needs to change `last --> break` to stop looping